# Lubuntu 18.04.3: cannot lower screen resolution

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, hp, display-resolution

I've just bought a new HP laptop 15-dw0004nl. I actually have a dual boot, Windows 10 and Lubuntu 18.04.3.

In 'monitor settings' there is only the FHD resolution as available, I cannot change it to a lower resolution (most comfortable for me). The output of xrandr gives also only that resolution:`

```
    Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.06*+  40.04
```

I've tried both drivers, Nouveau and Nvidia, it doesn't change the problem.

What could I do?

Thanks in advance!

Andrea

Comment: Nobody can help me? I've googled, but I didn't find so much, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2428469

I hope this will be useful to everybody with a similar problem to mine.